# Android HTTP connection to micro controller refused

Tags: android, httprequest

I'm trying to make an HTTP request to my micro controller on IP 192.168.1.7 but the connection gets refused. If I open it on the phone browser it works perfect. Here is my request function

```
class MakeRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}


private void makeRequest(String s) throws IOException {
    Log.e("TEST",s);
    String IP= "http://192.168.1.7/";
    String url=IP+s;

    MakeRequest req = new MakeRequest();

    req.execute(new String[] { url });
}
```

I've also added the permission to my manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The error log is :

```
05-18 17:14:50.979  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/tcmclient.jar
05-18 17:14:50.980  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.7 refused
05-18 17:14:50.980  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:193)
05-18 17:14:50.980  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
05-18 17:14:50.980  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
05-18 17:14:50.980  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)
05-18 17:14:50.980  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
05-18 17:14:50.980  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
05-18 17:14:50.980  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
05-18 17:14:50.980  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at com.reuben.machinecontrol.MainActivity$MakeRequest.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:194)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at com.reuben.machinecontrol.MainActivity$MakeRequest.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:185)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:619)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:198)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:689)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:849)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:124)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
05-18 17:14:50.981  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
05-18 17:14:50.982  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-18 17:14:50.982  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
05-18 17:14:50.982  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:282)
05-18 17:14:50.982  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:604)
05-18 17:14:50.982  27210-27565/com.reuben.machinecontrol W/System.err﹕ ... 19 more
```

Also I do not have any proxy connections. Again, it works perfect from the mobile browser but the connection gets refused in the app.

Comment: does this microcontroller have some kind of authentication?

Comment: Nothing of that sort. As I said it works perfectly from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the manifest was corrupted. Re-typed everything and it worked.